# YUI: adding event at the top of some event queue after page loading?

Tags: events, yui

How can I put a new event at the top of all attached events linked to an object just after the page load?

Pratically I have an accordion using some YUI funcs to activate its behavior, now without modifying the YUI main function I need some new functions used to call AJAX routines.
Currently I am trying with Event.getListeners, but I don't know how to treat the returned objects.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The responses you get from Event.getListeners is all the arguments passed into the Event.addListener. According to the [docs for Event.getListeners](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Event.html#method_getListeners) it returns

> ```
> the listener. Contains the following fields:   
>     type: (string) the type of event   
>     fn: (function) the callback supplied to addListener   
>     obj: (object) the custom object supplied to addListener   
>     adjust: (boolean|object) whether or not to adjust the default context   
>     scope: (boolean) the derived context based on the adjust parameter 
>     index: (int) its position in the Event util listener cache
> ```

So using that object you can probably just remove the Listeners using [Event.removeListener](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Event.html#method_removeListener) & then re-add them all in the order you want using Event.addListener. The object's properties map 1:1 with the args for Event.addListener so nothing will be lost.